# How can I use ILogger<T> from an Azure Functions V2 function?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I have some services that were initially designed to be called from my ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application. They have dependencies injected to their constructors using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package stuff. Some of them have a dependency of ILogger logger.

```
public GroupService(ILogger<GroupService> logger)
{
    ...
}
```

I am building a service provider within the function so that they can still work as expected however I'm wondering what I should do about the logger dependencies. An Azure Function (V2) gets an ILogger injected into it by default but that can't be used in the DI container to create the additional loggers that the services require.

Is there a LoggerFactory registered somewhere "under the covers" that I can get access to to be used in my DI container? I think that would allow me to add additional loggers that log to the functions output window or am I completely misunderstanding how logging in a function would work?

Do I just need to set up a new LoggerFactory and make that log to the ApplicationInsights instance used by the functions project?

Comment: You can use log4net for logging

Answer (score 1):

Using the [most recent Azure Function runtime](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.12265), you can now have the runtime inject your dependencies through constructors.

You can now remove the static keywords from your Azure Function and have the runtime.

Here is how you can set this up:

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(StartUp))]

public class StartUp : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder)
    {
        // Enables logging and sets the minimum level of logs.
        webJobsBuilder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        });

        // Registers your services.
        webJobsBuilder.Services.AddTransient<IGroupService, GroupService>();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 
Do you just put this somewhere in your functions project?
How does it play with other default options the functions team have in place? Does it break those configurations?

Comment: I just put the Startup file in the project where my functions are. I am not sure how it behaves if the other functions are still static and do not necessarily benefit from the injection. I guess it could be considered a good practice to have all the functions in a Function App to follow a similar approach... What do you think?

Comment: Yeah I think that you would probably want them to follow a similar approach within a function app. My main concern is that I suspect that the functions team have an implementation of the `IWebJobsStartup` interface that is being used by the runtime and overriding that may remove some of their configuration.